# How to write to a HTML file from a dictionary

Tags: python, html, dictionary

```
features = get_featuresreply(features_reply)
with open('index1.html', 'w') as report:
    report.write('<html>')
    report.write('<body>')

    for key,value in flow_stats.itervalues():
        report.write(key)
        report.write(value)
```

My features dictionary looks like this

```
{
"1": {
        "Port  hw_addr": "[62, 74, 73, 133, 83, 75]", 
        "Port A advertised": 0, 
        "Port A config": 0, 
        "Port A curr": 192, 
        "Port A name": "veth0", 
        "Port A peer": 0, 
        "Port A state": 0, 
        "Port A supported": 0, 
        "port_no": 1
    }, 
    "2": {
        "Port  hw_addr": "[18, 24, 239, 62, 79, 131]", 
        "Port A advertised": 0, 
        "Port A config": 0, 
        "Port A curr": 192, 
        "Port A name": "veth2", 
        "Port A peer": 0, 
        "Port A state": 0, 
        "Port A supported": 0, 
        "port_no": 2
    }, 
    "3": {
        "Port  hw_addr": "[134, 91, 48, 58, 109, 123]", 
        "Port A advertised": 0, 
        "Port A config": 0, 
        "Port A curr": 192, 
        "Port A name": "veth4", 
        "Port A peer": 0, 
        "Port A state": 0, 
        "Port A supported": 0, 
        "port_no": 3
    }, 
    "4": {
        "Port  hw_addr": "[182, 146, 36, 212, 132, 231]", 
        "Port A advertised": 0, 
        "Port A config": 0, 
        "Port A curr": 192, 
        "Port A name": "veth6", 
        "Port A peer": 0, 
        "Port A state": 0, 
        "Port A supported": 0, 
        "port_no": 4
    }, 
    "65534": {
        "Port  hw_addr": "[0, 35, 32, 82, 18, 23]", 
        "Port A advertised": 0, 
        "Port A config": 0, 
        "Port A curr": 130, 
        "Port A name": "tap0", 
        "Port A peer": 0, 
        "Port A state": 0, 
        "Port A supported": 0, 
        "port_no": 65534
    }, 
    "No of Ports": 5, 
    "No of Tables": "2", 
    "OFPAT_ENQUEUE": true, 
    "OFPAT_OUTPUT": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_DL_DST": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_DL_SRC": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_NW_DST": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_NW_TOS": false, 
    "OFPAT_SET_TP_DST": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_TP_SRC": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_VLAN_PCP": true, 
    "OFPAT_SET_VLAN_VID": true, 
    "OFPAT_STRIP_VLAN": true, 
    "OFPC_ARP_MATCH_IP": true, 
    "OFPC_FLOW_STATS": true, 
    "OFPC_IP_REASM": false, 
    "OFPC_PORT_STATS": true, 
    "OFPC_QUEUE_STATS": true, 
    "OFPC_RESERVED": false, 
    "OFPC_STP": false, 
    "OFPC_TABLE_STATS": true, 
    "buffer_size": "256", 
    "datapath_id": true
}
```

I'm not able to write this dict into a HTML file. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
  report.write(value)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I think the problem is because the dictionary is nested and Im not able to write that to a HTML file

Comment: looks like `flow_stats.itervalues()` is evaluating to an int

Comment: Please don't just change the question every time we fix an issue.

Comment: Sorry just wanted to let you the know the exact problem.I didn't explain the problem clearly the first time.

Comment: If you'd like to not go crazy writing HTML like this, take a look at http://genshi.edgewall.org/

Comment: Thanks,Will look into it.seems something like jinja2

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over *just* the values, not key-value pairs. Use `iteritems()` instead:

```
for key,value in flow_stats.iteritems():
    print key
    print value
```

Next, when writing integers (or anything else not a string) to files, convert these to strings first:

```
for key,value in flow_stats.iteritems():
    report.write(key)
    report.write(str(value))
```

But making use of [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) would make your task far easier:

```
for key,value in flow_stats.iteritems():
    report.write('<div>{}</div><div>{}</div>\n'.format(key, value))
```

as string formatting allows you to add static strings and define *how* values are converted to strings.

Comment: Comments are not a place to ask *new* questions, especially not if they involve code. Let's leave *this* question focused on one specific problem, new problems are best left to a *new* question.